# How do you manage bdd features and scenarios?

Tags: .net, testing, bdd, behavior, specflow

We are adopting BDD using specflow. The issue we have is that product owners and managers can not be expected to go into Visual studio / svn and edit features or scenarios.

We can get the pm's to do it all in google docs, and then we can copy and paste them into feature files, but this will be error prone and will get out of sync very quickly.

What is the best practice for managing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Product owners or business analysts should, in general, not be writing features on their own, as this can lead to poorly structured, untestable scenarios.

A common approach is known as 'the three amigos' - a business stakeholder, developer and tester working together to write scenarios.

It's fine to use Google Docs for the initial draft, but after that the features should be stored in version control, and the PO/BA should collaborate with a developer who has source control access on making changes.

You should make the version-controlled feature files easily accessible for review and reference to business stakeholders by linking to them from your intranet or wiki, or using a tool such as [Relish](https://www.relishapp.com/).

Comment: Agreed. Despite being human-readable, Gherkins are still code -and non-coders will break them faster than you can say "gazpacho soup"

Answer (score 0):

What we have done in the company I work for is, most of the Business Analysts (which are the ones that write the stories) know how to use SVN, write the stories and even run the tests (in our case it's not Specflow but Cucumber). He is the one that talks with product owners/managers to write the new features/requirements as stories. In other words, delegate the task to someone (either a BA or a QA) who has some experience writing stories or scenarios and be able to run them and troubleshoot if something bad happens. Communication is the base of this. If you don't have this person, well... try to get it :)

Answer (score 0):

[Matt Wynne on Using Cucumber](http://rubysource.com/matt-wynne-on-using-cucumber/) is a good read. Getting everyone talking ubiquitous language and having a single point of truth for the whole team.

Check out Pickles for outputting your features nicely https://github.com/x97mdr/pickles/wiki